# Google calendar java api: how to search events by attendee details (email, name etc.)

Tags: events, search, google-calendar-api

Is this possible to search google calendar events by some attendee details (name, email etc.) using Google Calendar Java API? I am able to search events by text using CalendarQuery which searches the events having given text in their title or description.
Is there any parameter available in the query to get events filtered by given attendee email, name etc.?